# Entire view is animating in from the top-left

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

Hey there internet reader,

I'm building a small feature where my banner animates in from the top using Snapkit and Combine. In my `viewDidLoad`, I call `setupObservers` which creates this publisher below.

Deeper in my app, `isShown` is toggled so that the publisher fires when the view is seen for the first time, causing not just the banner but the entire view to animate in from the top left, 0,0 position.

I know this is because I'm calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`, I'm just curious how to mitigate this so I can get the view to load in without animation, *then* show the banner.

Thanks!

```
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupObservers()

        viewStore.send(.viewDidLoad)
    }
```

```
        viewStore.publisher
            .banner
            .isShown
            .sink { isShown in
                guard self.initLoadFinished else { return }

                UIView.animate(withDuration: Metrics.animationDuration, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
                    self.banner.snp.updateConstraints {
                        if isShown {
                            self.topConstraint = $0.top.equalToSuperview()
                        } else {
                            self.topConstraint = $0.top.equalToSuperview().offset(-Metrics.bannerHeight)
                        }
                    }
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }.store(in: &cancellables)
```

Comment: Hi Zack, nice to see you here from better programming! But anyway try `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` right after the `guard self.initLoadFinished` first, so everything is layouted. Then, do what @Sh_Khan said below.

Comment: Hah, thanks aheze. Small world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get setting the constant out of the animation block

```
self.banner.snp.updateConstraints {
    if isShown {
         self.topConstraint.update(offset: 0)  
    } else {
         self.topConstraint.update(offset:-Metrics.bannerHeight)
    }
}  
UIView.animate(withDuration: Metrics.animationDuration, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut) { 
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded() 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still causes the whole view to animate in from the top left

Comment: create the constraint once and set it's constant only see edit

Comment: topConstraint isn't a typical `NSLayoutConstraint`, it's one of SnapKit's `ConstraintMakerEditable` types which doesn't have a `constant` property. So this won't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks. I discovered that as well. It's still animating the whole view in and not just the banner, however

Comment: `view.banner.layoutIfNeeded()` doesn't work either